# JqueryUI tooltip prevents <select> element dropdown from staying down in IE 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

When I open this HTML in IE 11 and allow scripting, a click on the dropdown causes it to flash up and immediately disappear. Any ideas?

This is from a much larger app, with styles and other elements, but here is the minimum to reproduce it.

I've left in a few tricks I tried to counteract this - in the onclick and onmouseover you can see script I have that tries to remove the attributes. However, whatever breaks the dropdown has already corrupted it. It even occurs when I remove the script at the top of the HTML to make the tooltip appear; it doesn't appear, but the dropdown is still broken.

```
<html>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("[data-tooltip-open=true]").tooltip({
                items: "[data-content=true]", content: $(this).data('content'),
                position: {
                    my: "center bottom-20",
                    at: "center top",                    
                    using: function (position, feedback) {
                        $(this).css(position);
                        $("<div>")
                          .addClass("arrow")
                          .addClass(feedback.vertical)
                          .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
                          .appendTo(this);
                    }
                }
            }).tooltip("open");
        });
    </script><body>
<form>
<select name="test"   
title="A selection from this list is required." 
data-tooltip-open="true" data-content="true" 
onclick="$(this).attr('data-tooltip-open','false');$(this).attr('title','');$(this).attr('data-content','false');" 
onmouseover="$(this).attr('data-tooltip-open','false');$(this).attr('title','');$(this).attr('data-content','false');">
 <option value=""></option>
 <option value=" "> </option>
 <option value="1">Option 1</option>
 <option value="2">Option 2</option>
 <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help appreciated. thanks.

Comment: What does the `data-tooltip-open` attribute do, or what is it supposed to do?

Comment: Instead of `$(this).attr('data-tooltip-open','false');$(this).attr('title','');$(this).attr('data-content','false');` you can use a chain `$(this).attr('data-tooltip-open','false').attr('title','').attr('data-content','false');` and the problem is that your `onclick=` interferes with the work of the tooltip script.

Comment: Cheery, thanks for the tip, that would make the code look better. However that was the code that I'd left in the sample to let people know what I'd tried - the problem occurs without it there at all.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For weird reasons, setting the title `$(this).attr('title', '')` or `this.title = ''` is closing the drop down.

Try below HTML in **IE11**

Code using jQuery `.attr`,

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="test" title="A selection from this list is required." onclick="$(this).attr('title', '')">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=" "></option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

Code using `this.title`,

```html
<select name="test" title="A selection from this list is required." onclick="this.title = (this.title == '')?'Test':'';">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=" "></option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

After narrowing it down, I also found this issue in jQuery bug tracker http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/8798

## Solution:

Now that we know the reason, you can avoid using title attribute to manage your tooltip, instead use a data say `customtooltip` and use it in the plugin.

```
<select name="test" 
       data-tooltip-open="true" 
       data-content="true" 
       data-customtooltip="A selection from this list is required.">
```

and then in the plugin options:

```
content: $("[data-tooltip-open=true]").data('customtooltip'),
```

Try below in IE 11 and let me know..

```js
$(function() {
  $("[data-tooltip-open=true]").tooltip({
    items: "[data-content=true]",
    content: $("[data-tooltip-open=true]").data('customtooltip'),
    position: {
      my: "center bottom-20",
      at: "center top",
      using: function(position, feedback) {
        $(this).css(position);
        $("<div>")
        .addClass("arrow")
        .addClass(feedback.vertical)
        .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
        .appendTo(this);
      }
    }
  }).tooltip("open");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<select name="test" data-tooltip-open="true" data-content="true" data-customtooltip="A selection from this list is required.">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=" "></option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```