# Tooltip shows the same message for different element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am using the jQueryUI tooltip in my application. The tooltip is working fine for all browsers except for ie11 for one case. If select is used in IE11 dropdown close automatically. For this, I found [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26936300/jqueryui-tooltip-prevents-select-element-dropdown-from-staying-down-in-ie-11) link to solve this issue. It's working perfect for one element, if we are using more than one element(e.g. two select and one text field) it always show message getting from first customtooltip.

How can I achieve this?
Here is code snippet below. you can check

```js
$(function() {
  $("[data-tooltip-open=true]").tooltip({
    items: "[data-content=true]",
    content: $("[data-tooltip-open=true]").data('customtooltip'),
    position: {
      my: "center bottom-20",
      at: "center top",
      using: function(position, feedback) {
        $(this).css(position);
        $("<div>")
        .addClass("arrow")
        .addClass(feedback.vertical)
        .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
        .appendTo(this);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<select name="test" data-tooltip-open="true" data-content="true" data-customtooltip="First tooltip message.">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=" "></option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<select name="test" data-tooltip-open="true" data-content="true" data-customtooltip="Second tooltip message.">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=" "></option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<input data-tooltip-open="true" data-content="true" data-customtooltip="Third tooltip message.">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
content: $("[data-tooltip-open=true]").data('customtooltip'),
```

It takes all elements with specified selector and tries to get the `data` attribute. As long as there are more than one, it takes the first.

Try to use `function` here:

```js
$(function() {
  $("[data-tooltip-open=true]").tooltip({
    items: "[data-content=true]",
    content: function(){ return $(this).data('customtooltip') },
    position: {
      my: "center bottom-20",
      at: "center top",
      using: function(position, feedback) {
        $(this).css(position);
        $("<div>")
        .addClass("arrow")
        .addClass(feedback.vertical)
        .addClass(feedback.horizontal)
        .appendTo(this);
      }
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<select name="test" data-tooltip-open="true" data-content="true" data-customtooltip="First tooltip message.">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=" "></option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>

<select name="test" data-tooltip-open="true" data-content="true" data-customtooltip="Second tooltip message.">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value=" "></option>
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</option>
  <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<input data-tooltip-open="true" data-content="true" data-customtooltip="Third tooltip message.">
```